# what is the bound when integrating f(x.y)=1 when x=y?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Function f is defined f(x.y)=1 if x=y and 0 if x is not equal to 0

x is [0.1] and y is [0.1]

when double-integrating this, what would be the bound for integral?

Comment: The line $y=x$ would provide one of the bounds. Have you sketched the region where $f$ is $1$?

Comment: isn't that just one line segment from (0.0) to (1.1)?

Comment: @nancy What is the area of a line segment?  That answer is the "measure" of the line segment in $R^2$.  See my answer in which I show that the area of the line segment is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $1>\delta>0$ and define a sub-region $Q_{\delta}$ as the region in $Q$ for which $\max(0,x-\delta)<y<\min(x+\delta,1)$.  Notice that

$$0\le\int \int_{Q_{\delta}} f(x,y)dxdy\le1 \int \int_{Q_{\delta}} dxdy$$ 
$$=1\left(1-\left(1-\delta^2\right)\right)$$
$$=\delta (2-\delta)$$
$$<2\delta$$

Thus, the integral can be made smaller than any pre-chosen $\epsilon>0$ by choosing $\delta<\frac12 \epsilon$.  This should lead immediately to the conclusion that the double integral is zero in the sense of Lebesgue.

If this is a Riemann integral, one partitions the rectangle in a set of sub-rectangles.  Note that for any such partition, one can show that the area of the set of rectangles along the diagonal (on which $f=1$) goes to zero as the norm of the net of this partition goes to zero.  In fact, these rectangles along the diagonal can be contained in a region $Q_{\delta}$ as before.

Answer (score 0):

If $\;f(x, y)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\neq y \\ 1 & x=y\end{cases}\;$, then $\quad\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x, y) \operatorname d y\operatorname d x = 0$

Line segments have zero measurable area.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. one more question, to prove that this integral exists, I think the best way to show is that inff=supf. someone told me that inf of f is 1, but it seems like sup of f is 0. how does inf of f =1 ? is my TA wrong?

Comment: The $\sup$ is the least upper bound, which is $0$ here.  The $\inf$ is the greatest lower bound, which is $0$ here.

Comment: @Graham.  Of course, that argument is not valid for Riemann integrals. One would have to form a partition and show that the sum over the net of $\sup f$ and $inf f$ can be made arbitrarily close.